# PHP gallery, thumbnail listing

Tags: php, html, css, gallery, photo

I am planning a dynamic PHP photo gallery and having difficulty deciding on the best way to display the thumbnails after they have been retrieved via MySQL. I considered using an inline unordered list but this resulted in the thumbs being stacked one on top of the other (touching). Also tried a table but not sure how I would start the next row after x number of thumbnails.

Any suggestions on page layout for this purpose? I will be using Lightbox to cycle through the photos themselves, that isn't the issue.

Also, would a while() loop be best for fetching the list of thumbs and inserting the appropriate HTML?

Thanks!

-Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's a HTML/CSS question (except the while() loop part).

Hard to tell why thumbnails touch each other. Make them float to the left and set up sufficient margins around thumbnail wrappers, e.g.

`div.thumbnail { float:left; margin:10px; padding:8px; border:1px solid #aaa; }`

Re. loop, yes, typically you would use a while () loop like this:

```
$query = "select * from images where 1";
$result = mysql_query ($query);
if (mysql_num_rows ($result) > 0) {
    while ($image = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
        ... your action with this image here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for forgetting those tags! And thank you so much! I think my brain is stuck in PHP mode, forgot that simple bit of CSS for this. Should be good to go from here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of using a list is a good one.  You need to correct the CSS so that your images appear the way that you want to.

[W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) has a good starter css reference, and [CSS Zend Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) can give you an idea of what can be accomplished with css.

Maybe you could describe exactly what layout issue you're having?